# Twilio return self._qs.unescape error

Tags: node.js, meteor, twilio

when i use Twilio to send SMS it return
**TypeError: self._qs.unescape is not a function** 
 packaje.json :

```
"dependencies": {

    "twilio": "^2.11.1",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.6",
    "@types/twilio": "0.0.9"
  }
```

And My Code :

```
 var twilio = require('twilio');

 var ACCOUNT_SID = "***";
 var AUTH_TOKEN = "***";
  TwilioClient.messages.create({
       body: 'Welcome  ',
       to:  '+*****'
       from: '+****' // From a valid Twilio number
   }).then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

and returned :
**Exception in delivering result of invoking 'Register': TypeError: self._qs.unescape is not a function**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Meteor, I should connect to the Twilio API from the server.

When I requested from the client, I got the error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to initiate the twilio client and then use it :

```
var client = new twilio(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

client.messages.create({
       body: 'Welcome  ',
       to:  '+*****'
       from: '+****' // From a valid Twilio number
}).then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```